# tastypie path to resources

Tags: django, api, django-models, tastypie

I'm setting up related fields in my tastypie api.

I have this in my api.py file:

```
class PeopleResource(ModelResource):
event_id = fields.ForeignKey(EventResource,'event', full=True)
answer_link = fields.ForeignKey(DatePeopleResource,'datepeople', full=True, related_name='datepeople')
class Meta:
    queryset = EventPeople.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'people'
    filtering = {
        'event_id' : ALL,
        'phone_number' : ALL,
        'name' : ALL,
        'answer' : ALL,
    }
    authorization = Authorization()



class DatePeopleResource(ModelResource):
event = fields.ForeignKey(EventResource,'event')
event_date = fields.ForeignKey(DateResource,'event_date')
event_person = fields.ForeignKey(PeopleResource,'event_person', related_name='people')
class Meta:
    queryset = DatePeople.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'datepeople'
    filtering = {
        'event' : ALL,
        'event_person' : ALL,
        'event_date' : ALL,
    }
    authorization = Authorization()
```

My problem is that the DatePeopleResource field related to the PeopleResource works, but the first one doesn't work. (the one related to DatePeopleResource from PeopleResource)

I guess this is because DatePeopleResource isn't defined yet. In the tastypie doc it looks like I have to add the path.to.api.resource before calling DatePeopleResource, like this :

```
answer_link = fields.ForeignKey(path.to.resource.DatePeopleResource,'datepeople', full=True, related_name='datepeople')
```

But I have no idea what the path is ! I tried 'resources','api'... I don't really understand what this path is.

Thank you for your help, I'm stuck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the resource is something like

```
"appname.api.classname"
```

and don't forget to put it into quotes, because yes, it is not yet defined when you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also import DatePeopleResource and then use it to define relation with it.
for ex:

```
from ..api import DatePeopleResource

class EventResource(ModelResource):
     event = fields.ForeignKey(DatePeopleResource, 'event')
```

On that way the code is cleaner.